# Qwik ecosystem’s answer to Formik

Tags: formik, qwik

Since Qwik is React-like and not a React runtime, not all of the popular libraries that exist in the React ecosystem exist in the Qwik ecosystem. Is there an existing Qwik alternative to Formik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow Qwik-react project to know how to use React components in Qwik.

https://qwik.builder.io/qwikcity/integrations/react/

I don't think at the moment we have any thing alternative for Formik in Qwik

Answer (score 0):

For basic applications, the default Qwik  component is good enough.

If you want a feature rich form, try [Modular Forms](https://modularforms.dev/qwik/guides/handle-submission)